# How to set the control template in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

How do you set the `.Template` property of an element (e.g. a `FlipViewItem` in my case) using C# code to a predefined one in my `StandardStyles.xaml`

This is the template if it's relevant:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DocumentFlipViewItemControlTemplate" TargetType="FlipViewItem">
    <Grid Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <MyProject:DocumentTabControl Name="MainDocumentTabControl"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Please note this is a different question from [How to set Control Template in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755455/how-to-set-control-template-in-code) - that question creates a template on the fly and then assigns it to the control, I just want to set a predefined template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <Style x:Key="DocumentFlipViewItemStyle" TargetType="FlipViewItem" >
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DocumentFlipViewItemControlTemplate}"/>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Could a style be used for the a specific `FlipView` to cause all it's `FlipViewItem`s to have the same template?

Comment: I am not familiar with this control, but if it has ItemContainerStyle property, you should set it: ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DocumentFlipViewItemStyle}"

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
TargetType="FlipViewItem"
```

to something like this:

```
TargetType="{x:Type FlipViewItem}"
```

And that will apply the style to that `type` across the application. Now one thing to note is that you may need the namespace declaration in front of your type. So, if it's coming from something other than the standard libraries you may need something like:

```
TargetType="{x:Type local:FlipViewItem}"
```

Comment: Okay, that's pretty close, however I have other `FlipViewItem`s that I don't want to use this template, is there a way to set the template for a specific instance of a `FlipViewItem`?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but you can simply assign it like this:

```
var template = 
    (ControlTemplate)Application.Current
        .MainWindow // Your WPF window.
        .FindResource("DocumentFlipViewItemControlTemplate");
```

and then you assign it to your `FlipViewItem` like this:

```
var flipItem = new FlipViewItem { Template = template };
```