# How to code Orientation of ListBox - WPF - c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I need set Orientation to ListBox in C# code. I need the same result like this XAML code:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

I have this:

```
ListBox elementListBox = new ListBox();
StackPanel pomocnyStackPanel = new StackPanel();
pomocnyStackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
```

How to add "ItemsPanel"?

Comment: you can check this question, it solves a similar problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755455/how-to-set-control-template-in-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously could do it using `FrameworkElementFactory` but it's now deprecated and they suggest using  [`XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) instead:

```
elementListBox.ItemsPanel = (ItemsPanelTemplate)XamlReader.Parse("<ItemsPanelTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><StackPanel Orientation=\"Horizontal\"/></ItemsPanelTemplate>");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you want something like this:

```
FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
factory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
ItemsPanelTemplate itemsPanelTemplate = new ItemsPanelTemplate(factory);
ListBox elementListBox = new ListBox();
elementListBox.ItemsPanel = itemsPanelTemplate;
```

UPDATE >>>

Yep, I just tested it and it works as expected.