# How to translate wpf xaml controltemplate and its content to c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I’ve got this piece of XAML in WPF, and I’d like to translate it to C# but I cannot find any way of doing it.

```
<Style x:Key="OptionsStyle" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
    <Style.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources;component/BorderStyle.xaml" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource FormBorderStyle}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is what I tried

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        Template = new ControlTemplate(typeof(UserControl))
        {
            SOMETHING (there is not big choice here :( ) = new ContentPresenter() { Content = FindResource("FormBorderStyle") }
        };
    }
}
```

I just can’t find a way to put that ContentPresenter into that ControlTemplate, or maybe it should be something else instead of ControlTemplate?

Kind Regards

Comment: Why would you want to replace perfectly usable XAML with suboptimal C#?

Comment: @MikeEason I am implementing some custom behaviours and custom controls, and this is just a code snipped of a much bigger control.

Comment: @adminSoft. Do you really want to change the Template of control with C#, or is ok for you to change Content property to provide custom Content to your UserControl with C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `VisualTree` property of the `ControlTemplate`, which if of type `FrameworkElementFactory`.
Alternatively, you can use `XamlReader` if you can keep the content of your ControlTemplate in Xaml.
See [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755455/how-to-set-control-template-in-code).